# How to Remove space inside the String in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datetime, datatable, datetime-format

I am taking values from database into datatable. After that I am filtering on a single column in which I have one `Date Time` value.

What I want is to Trim the space between the Date And Column which is retrieved added when I get the data to filter in Jquery.

```
function SomeCol(_filterType, _txtVal, Data, data, _txtValTo) {
      var value = true;
      var regx = new RegExp('\{\".*?:.*?\"\}');
      var match = '';
      var json = regx.exec(data[Data]);
      if (json != null) {
        data[Data] = data[Data].replace(json, '');
      }
      switch (_filterType) {
        case "Equals": //Equals
          if (_txtVal != '') {
            if (data[Data].toString().trim() == _txtVal.trim()) {
              value = true;
            } else {
              value = false;
            }
          }
          break;
      }
}
```

In `_txtVal` I get `31/8/2015 01:15 pm` (One space) [_txtVal comes from Datatable]

In `data[Data].toString()` I get `31/8/2015  01:15 pm` (Two Spaces)

Is there any way so I can remove that extra space between the "data[Data]"

Comment: could you please reformat your question. I think some text got mixed with code block. It will be easy to read it if you do that.

Comment: When in the process does it appear that the extra space is being added?

Comment: in _txtVal I get 31/8/2015 01:15 pm(One space) [_txtVal comes from Datatable]
    in data[Data].toString() I get 31/8/2015  01:15 pm (Two Spaces)
    so is there any way so I can remove that extra space between the "data[Data]"

Comment: How are you populating `_txtVal` and `data[Data]` - doesn't appear to be a jquery issue but a data retrieval issue in your server-side / back-end.

Comment: @jonmrich yes in jquery one space get added here

Comment: There's no code to "add" a space - so the space is already there in the data.  What data type is `data[Data]` ?  Could be the `.toString()` but unlikely.

Comment: _txtVal comes from TextBox and data[Data] comes from datatable row

Comment: @freedomn-m thanx for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could try replacing the two spaces with one.

```
data[Data].toString().replace("  ", " ");
```

Comment: No problem :) If it's not too much to ask please accept my answer

Comment: my reputation lil low right now m new to stack overflow but i ll do it for sure

Answer (score 3):

Use @strapro's answer if there's just once instance of two spaces to replace. Use the following if there're multiple:

```
data[Data].toString().replace(/  /g, ' ');
```